# Status from gitlab-ci not showing up anymore on gitlab merge request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Gitlab-CI works perfectly as far as I can tell. It runs and does everything as it should, but gitlab itself doesn't show the status.

All I keep seeing is "Checking for CI status for x" with the spinner standing still.

The only clue I get is from the gitlab production.log when I open the page:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed):
  app/models/project_services/gitlab_ci_service.rb:39:in `commit_status'
  app/controllers/projects/merge_requests_controller.rb:165:in `ci_status'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:57:in `set_current_user_for_thread'
```

This is odd to say the least. Everything else works fine, so it doesn't seem systemic to gitlab as a whole.

Gitlab details:

```
GitLab 6.6.4
GitLab Shell 1.8.4
GitLab API v3
Ruby 1.9.3p194
Rails 4.0.3
GitLab CI 4.3.0 267edb0
```

I searched around and did not find similar problems. It's puzzling since it stopped working after an upgrade from 6.something to 6.6.4 in gitlab. This is not a critical piece, but removes some of the easy use of the CI server.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're using self-signed certificates? I had to patch my Gitlab CI [like this](https://gist.github.com/milgner/23544a28b9045fccab35) and then set `config.verify_ssl = false`.
Edit: maybe I should make a pull request out of it? :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @ma_li, the error is most likely due to the self-signed certificate. You should avoid using self-signed certificates on public URLs, as this is rather easy to hack. Instead, if you do not want to buy, you can request a free SSL cert eg. from StartSSL https://www.startssl.com/

Comment: You should **not** use a StartSSL cert, as they are untrusted by Chrome. Let's Encrypt is a better alternative.

Comment: I absolutely agree, this is true as for today :) StartSSL was invalidated since I've written my answer.